# NHibernate Queries with Common Table Expression

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, common-table-expression

I have an SQL Server query of the kind:

```
WITH MostRecentToday AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ItemGuid ORDER BY Version DESC) AS rn
    FROM Items
    WHERE Cast(Timestamp As date) = '2023-06-08' and ABC = 'foo' and XYZ = 123
)
SELECT *
FROM MostRecentToday
WHERE rn = 1
```

How can I write this as an NHibernate query? There doesn't seem to be much information publically available that indicates how to write an NHibernate query which uses Common Table Expressions.

Comment: You can use a regular subquery, no need for cte in this case. select * from ( select row_number() .... ) where rn = 1. Does that help?

Comment: Side note `WHERE Cast(Timestamp As date) = '2023-06-08'` is not performant, instead do `WHERE Timestamp >= '20230608' AND Timestamp < '20230609'`

Comment: Use following : https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/org.hibernate.Session/createSQLQuery?force_isolation=true

Comment: You could create your query as a view and then just map to the view, or create it as a tvf and select from that if you need to paramterise anything.

Comment: No point tagging SQL Server, you're looking for an nhibernate expert not an SQL Server expert. You should also show the actual requirements i.e. I have this sample data and I need to obtain these results, rather than expecting someone to interpret your query.